# turn off javapns.Push.combined debug mode

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am using javapns and it works fine but every time it sends a notification, it logs everything which is populating my log file. How can I stop logging the activity of javapns? This is my code

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();
devices.add("deviceID");
Push.combined ("Test Notification...", 1, "bingbong.aiff", "ssl_cert.p12", "password",true, devices);
```

(I have set production mode to true).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JavaPNs used log4j for logging.

You can stop it with this configuration file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
 <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} 
      %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
   </layout>
 </appender>
 <root>
    <priority value="OFF"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

`<priority value="OFF"></priority>` stops all logging.
You can choose any of the following logging levels :

```
  /**
     The <code>OFF</code> has the highest possible rank and is
     intended to turn off logging.  */
  final static public Level OFF = new Level(OFF_INT, "OFF", 0);

  /**
     The <code>FATAL</code> level designates very severe error
     events that will presumably lead the application to abort.
   */
  final static public Level FATAL = new Level(FATAL_INT, "FATAL", 0);

  /**
     The <code>ERROR</code> level designates error events that
     might still allow the application to continue running.  */
  final static public Level ERROR = new Level(ERROR_INT, "ERROR", 3);

  /**
     The <code>WARN</code> level designates potentially harmful situations.
  */
  final static public Level WARN  = new Level(WARN_INT, "WARN",  4);

  /**
     The <code>INFO</code> level designates informational messages
     that highlight the progress of the application at coarse-grained
     level.  */
  final static public Level INFO  = new Level(INFO_INT, "INFO",  6);

  /**
     The <code>DEBUG</code> Level designates fine-grained
     informational events that are most useful to debug an
     application.  */
  final static public Level DEBUG = new Level(DEBUG_INT, "DEBUG", 7);

  /**
    * The <code>TRACE</code> Level designates finer-grained
    * informational events than the <code>DEBUG</code level.
   *  @since 1.2.12
    */
  public static final Level TRACE = new Level(TRACE_INT, "TRACE", 7);


  /**
     The <code>ALL</code> has the lowest possible rank and is intended to
     turn on all logging.  */
  final static public Level ALL = new Level(ALL_INT, "ALL", 7);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but If I change the servers configuration it will stop all the logging (I am not sure, can you please correct me if I am wrong). I only want to stop javapns logging... Thanks